# Geofire + CloudFunctions Firebase ERROR at GeoQuery

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, geofire

I am trying to create a server(cloud functions) script where certain keys are retrieved with the help of geofire and geoquery.

I dont know why but I am getting this error :

```
firebaseRef must be an instance of Firebase
    at new GeoQuery (/srv/node_modules/geofire/dist/index.cjs.js:505:19)
    at new GeoFire.query (/srv/node_modules/geofire/dist/index.cjs.js:1072:16)
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:43:22)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

my code below :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const GeoFire = require('geofire');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('MyData/').onWrite((change,context) => {

    const Locations = change.after.val(); //getting locations from triggering device

    const geofire = new GeoFire.GeoFire(admin.database().ref('/geofire'));

    const geoQuery = new geofire.query({ // <<=== giving error here in the Firebase Logs not while deploying
        center : [Locations.latitude,Locations.longitude], //this location is same as Firebase one
        radius : 10.0
    });

     const onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location) {
        console.log(key + " entered the query. Hi " + key + "!");
      });
}
```

Got something like this in npm

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: firebase@^2.4.0 || 3.x.x || 4.x.x || 5.x.x, required by geofire@5.0.1
```

[my Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBUPl.png)

Comment: How have you initialized geofire?

Comment: @Mobeen Yes I have already did

Comment: Can I see the code for import and intialization?

Comment: actually I have updated my code please can you check?